# Load UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have one UIViewController with a black background color and I do this:

```
CredenciaisViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Credencial"];
   [_viewContainer addSubview:obj.view];
    _viewContainer.alpha = 1;
```

CredenciaisViewController has red background color, but when it load half of my background is white.

And UiButtons when is in white part does not work too.

Why this happens?
And How can I fix it?

Comment: why are you doing this:
  [_viewContainer addSubview:obj.view];
???

Comment: Because I need to load a UIViewController in a UIView. I have some animations on my app and this content need to load inside this UIView.
Are there another way to do this?

Comment: I saw people adding UIView To UIViewController but the opposite!!!
even if you have some animations to do!

Do you need to show the ViewController as a dialog ??

Comment: I have some UIViewControllers with my contents.
And my main UIViewController has a menu, this menu has some animations when you choose a item of this menu a content load inside a UIView in the same page of my menu (The main page)

Comment: I tried to do this:
[self.view addSubview:obj.view];
And the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it! 
I put [Container View](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

And in my action button I did:

```
- (IBAction)mostrarCredenciais:(id)sender {
CredenciaisViewController *credenciaisView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Credencial"];

[self addChildViewController:credenciaisView];
[credenciaisView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
credenciaisView.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
[self.containerView addSubview:credenciaisView.view];
}
```

And then worked well!